# Find Point such that vectors are perpendicular

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given three points P,Q and R, how May I find another point O such that OP,OQ and OR are all perpendicular between themselves? I have no idea how to tackle this

Comment: you know about the theorem of Thales, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem?

Comment: Are you aware of orthocenter?

Comment: How is your reasoning when you say "May I find another point $O$ " Another one, but what is the first $O$ ??? You don't mention it. Usually $O$ is used for the circumcenter of a triangle.

Comment: Yes Aqua, I know the orthocenter.

Comment: First of all, decide if it's a 2d problem or a 3d problem.

Comment: It's a 3d problem

Comment: Ok, so next try to find relation/position of O wrt P, Q, R. Add your attempts to the post.

Comment: HINT. Point $O$ must lay on the sphere of diameter $PQ$... etc.